# sqlalchemy - Could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy to reflect an existing database with no foreign keys defined.  Given the following example:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(...)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.reflect(engine)

class A(Base):
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['A']


class B(Base):
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['B']

class C(Base):
    __table__ = sqlalchemy.outerjoin(A, B, onclause=A.foo==B.foo)
```

How can I limit the fields used in C?

I tried setting:

```
__mapper_args__ = {
    'include_properties': ['foo', 'bar']
}
```

But get error

```
Mapper Mapper|C|Join object on Join object on Join object on A(47698852085840) and B(47698852088016)(47698861282384) could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table
```